# Cocoapods error: cannot load such file -- macho

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I have an error when I try to install pod. I try to uninstall completely cocoapods and install it again but it doesn't work. I have no idea how to fix it I tried to install `macho` but it doesn't help.
It looks ok until `Generating Pods project` then it crashes
pod version 1.5.3

````
pod install


Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Adjust (4.8.5)
Using Crashlytics (3.10.7)
Using Fabric (1.7.11)
Using Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (7.33.1)
Using GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK (3.7.3)
Generating Pods project

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

### Command

```
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin/pod install
```

### Report

* What did you do?

* What did you expect to happen?

* What happened instead?


### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.5.3
        Ruby : ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [x86_64-darwin15]
    RubyGems : 2.6.10
        Host : Mac OS X 10.14 (18A391)
       Xcode : 9.4.1 (9F2000)
         Git : git version 2.16.2
Ruby lib dir : /Users/s/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 799ce6567dfe5da62ecdc3a7ba975737c7926347
```

### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.2
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.3.1
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0
```

### Podfile

```ruby
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
platform :ios, '9.0'
project 'BunteMobile.xcodeproj'
target 'BunteMobile' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for BunteMobile
  pod 'Adjust', '~> 4.8.3'
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
  pod 'GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.7'
  pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.0'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '~>  3.9'

  target 'BunteMobileTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

### Error

```
LoadError - cannot load such file -- macho
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/sandbox/file_accessor.rb:432:in `rescue in dynamic_binary?'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/sandbox/file_accessor.rb:427:in `dynamic_binary?'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/sandbox/file_accessor.rb:164:in `block in vendored_dynamic_frameworks'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/sandbox/file_accessor.rb:163:in `select'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/sandbox/file_accessor.rb:163:in `vendored_dynamic_frameworks'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/sandbox/file_accessor.rb:172:in `vendored_static_frameworks'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/sandbox/file_accessor.rb:238:in `vendored_static_artifacts'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/generator/xcconfig/aggregate_xcconfig.rb:56:in `block in generate'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/generator/xcconfig/aggregate_xcconfig.rb:56:in `any?'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/generator/xcconfig/aggregate_xcconfig.rb:56:in `generate'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/generator/xcconfig/aggregate_xcconfig.rb:39:in `save_as'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/target_installer.rb:112:in `update_changed_file'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/aggregate_target_installer.rb:96:in `block in create_xcconfig_file'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/aggregate_target_installer.rb:93:in `each'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/aggregate_target_installer.rb:93:in `create_xcconfig_file'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/aggregate_target_installer.rb:18:in `block in install!'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:142:in `message'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/aggregate_target_installer.rb:14:in `install!'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator.rb:181:in `block (2 levels) in install_libraries'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator.rb:179:in `each'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator.rb:179:in `block in install_libraries'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:142:in `message'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator.rb:167:in `install_libraries'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator.rb:65:in `generate!'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:184:in `block in generate_pods_project'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:183:in `generate_pods_project'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:119:in `install!'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:41:in `run'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin/pod:22:in `load'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/Users/s/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=cannot+load+such+file+--+macho&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
 - LoadError - cannot load such file -- macho
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7849 [closed] [7 comments]
   16 hours ago

 - LoadError - cannot load such file -- macho
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7867 [closed] [17 comments]
   5 weeks ago

 - LoadError - cannot load such file -- macho
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7864 [closed] [2 comments]
   21 Jun 2018

and 5 more at:
https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/search?q=cannot%20load%20such%20file%20--%20macho&type=Issues&utf8=✓
````

Comment: I installed 1.6.0.beta.1 and it starts work